# How to access method through ref React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to access a method from outside the component. I found several tutorials that should allow me to call methods by `window.PathfindingVisualizer.resetGrid()`, but I'm getting an error saying resetGrid is not a function

example I tried to follow: https://brettdewoody.com/accessing-component-methods-and-state-from-outside-react/

my App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <PathfindingVisualizer 
          ref={(PathfindingVisualizer) => {window.PathfindingVisualizer = PathfindingVisualizer}} 
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

my PathfindingVisualizer.js:

```
export default class PathfindingVisualizer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            grid: [],
            mouseLeftDown: false,
        };
        const mouseStrat = null;   
    }
    resetGrid() {
        //do stuff
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.resetGrid();
        this.mouseStrat = new MouseStrat();  //Object I want to call functions from
    }
}
```

And I want to call the `resetGrid()` and `setState` from outside of react with:

```
//errors resetGrid and setState is not a function

export class MouseStrat {
    handleMouseDown(row, col) {
        window.PathfindingVisualizer.resetGrid();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you log `window.PathfindingVisualizer` and check what are you getting?  Values in a ref are mostly available in its current property. You might want to check that.

Comment: console log:
`PathfindingVisualizer {props: {…}, context: {…}, refs: {…}, updater: {…}, resetGrid(): ƒ, …}
colorVisited: async visitedNodes => {…}
context: {}
mouseStrat2: StartEndStrat {}
props: {}
refs: {}
state: {grid: Array(10), mouseLeftDown: false}
updater: {isMounted: ƒ, enqueueSetState: ƒ, enqueueReplaceState: ƒ, enqueueForceUpdate: ƒ}
_reactInternalInstance: {_processChildContext: ƒ}
_reactInternals: FiberNode {tag: 1, key: null, stateNode: PathfindingVisualizer, elementType: ƒ, type: ƒ, …}
isMounted: (...)
replaceState: (...)
[[Prototype]]: Component`

Comment: It seems to get the correct component and I can see it has the functions inside

Comment: If possible, can you put a sandBox ? @Sujio

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling these functions? If they are being run too early `window.PathfindingVisualizer` may not have a value yet. You may want to run them in a hook like `componentDidUpdate`.

Comment: I'm trying to call it from an object created dynamically inside the PathfindingVisualizer component, adding code to my question now.

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand correctly, you have a component with a variable that is a class that contains a function that calls a function that's already in the component. This seems quite complicated, and there may be a simpler solution to what you're trying to achieve.

Here's an alternative solution. Make `resetGrid` function a property of the MouseStrat class:

```js
export class MouseStrat {
    constructor(resetGrid) {
        this.resetGrid = resetGrid;
    }
    handleMouseDown(row, col) {
        this.resetGrid();
    }
}
```

Then, in `PathfindingVisualizer`:

```js
export default class PathfindingVisualizer extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            grid: [],
            mouseLeftDown: false,
            mouseStrat: null // You had this as a variable before
        };
        this.resetGrid = this.resetGrid.bind(this); // You must bind your function for it to work properly in a React component
    }
    function resetGrid () { 
        //do stuff
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.resetGrid();
        this.mouseStrat = new MouseStrat(this.resetGrid); // Now you pass the function as an argument
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'm doing it this way because it is a strategy design pattern. I plan to implement _many functions and want to dynamically change which functions are called when an event happens. This is to avoid many if / switch statements later on when I implement more functions